# How do I change the colour of all select2 elements in a specific row

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-select2

I am using select2, but I would like to change the back-ground colour of all of the select elements in my table. However, the jQuery code I am running, only changes the colour of the first select input. Any tips for fixing this issue?

My html looks like

```
<table width="100%" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="TB2">
   <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Type of Student</th>
        <th>Thesis/ Project/ Research</th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
      <tr class="table_row">
         <td><input class="form-control alert-danger" type="text" name="a"/></td>
         <td><select class="form-control alert-danger"">
             <option value="">Type</option>
             <option>Bachelors</option>
             <option>Masters</option>
             <option>Doctoral</option>
             <option>Postdoctoral</option>
             </select></td>
          <td><select class="form-control">
              <option value="">Select</option>
              <option>Thesis</option>
              <option>Project</option>
              <option>Research</option>
              </select></td>
       </tr>
    </tbody>
 </table>
```

And my JQuery code looks like:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('select').select2({
        placeholder: "Select",
        allowClear: true
    });
    $('#TB2 tbody tr').find("select").data("select2").$container.find('.select2-selection').css("background-color", "rgb(10,10,10)");
});
```

The jQuery is successful in making the first select statement have the proper background, but does not affect the second. I need to make all the select elements in the entire row have a background of RGB(10,10,10). I also have other select inputs on other parts of my page, where I don't want to affect the background, so I need to affect only the tr.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is in this line:

```
$('#TB2 tbody tr').find("select").data("select2").......
```

The [.data("select2")](https://api.jquery.com/data/) returns only the first value and not an array of elements for which you want to change the background color.

You can use [.each()](https://api.jquery.com/each/) to iterate on each select tag.

```
$('#TB2 tbody tr').find("select").each(function(idx, ele) {
   $(ele).data("select2").$container.find('.select2-selection')
                     .css("background-color", "rgb(10,10,10)");
});
```

The snippet:

```js
$('select').select2({
    placeholder: "Select",
    allowClear: true
});
$('#TB2 tbody tr').find("select").each(function(idx, ele) {
   $(ele).data("select2").$container.find('.select2-selection')
           .css("background-color", "rgb(10,10,10)");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/js/select2.min.js"></script>


<table width="100%" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="TB2">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Type of Student</th>
        <th>Thesis/ Project/ Research</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr class="table_row">
        <td><input class="form-control alert-danger" type="text" name="a"/></td>
        <td><select class="form-control alert-danger"">
            <option value="">Type</option>
            <option>Bachelors</option>
            <option>Masters</option>
            <option>Doctoral</option>
            <option>Postdoctoral</option>
            </select></td>
        <td><select class="form-control">
            <option value="">Select</option>
            <option>Thesis</option>
            <option>Project</option>
            <option>Research</option>
        </select></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Yea but I do not want to change the colour of the dropdown, just the container is fine, but the problem is with making all of the containers in the one row have a background colour. Even in the code you supplied, look at the select with the options (Thesis, project, research), no effect on that one

Comment: Yes, that's correct. But not by ids or anything. For example, if I give all the tr input fields a colour of red, all of the text fields across the row will have a colour of red, but for these select elements, I want to affect all of them in the entire row, not just one

Comment: @Muhammad Answer and snippet updated. Let me know. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What library do you use for this example ...
I do not exactly understand

Maybe this example can be tried

```js
$(function () {
 $("select").change(function () {
  var $this = $(this).val();
   if ($this =="Bachelors") {
    alert('value = Bachelors');
        //more function here
        $('body').css({'background':'red'}); // example
        
        
   }
   if ($this =="Masters") {
    alert('value = Bachelors');
        //more function here
        $('body').css({'background':'blue'}); // example
        
        
   }
      //etc...
      
      
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table width="100%" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="TB2">
   <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Type of Student</th>
        <th>Thesis/ Project/ Research</th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
      <tr class="table_row">
         <td><input class="form-control alert-danger" type="text" name="a"/></td>
         <td><select class="form-control alert-danger">
             <option disabled value="">Type</option>
             <option>Bachelors</option>
             <option>Masters</option>
             <option>Doctoral</option>
             <option>Postdoctoral</option>
             </select></td>
          <td>
          <select class="form-control">
              <option disabled value="">Select</option>
              <option>Thesis</option>
              <option>Project</option>
              <option>Research</option>
          </select>
          </td>
       </tr>
    </tbody>
 </table>
```

**[FIIDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/q3292d39/)**